# Comparing datetimes and joining when they are within 5 minutes

Tags: ruby, arrays, datetime

I have a large array of DateTimes. For example:

```
[2013-06-17 19:47:12, 
 2013-06-17 19:40:01, 
 2013-06-17 19:42:53, 
 2013-06-17 19:12:27, 
 2013-06-17 19:45:42, 
 2013-06-17 19:14:17]... etc
```

What I'd like to do is iterate through the array and come up with a bunch of ranges for DateTime objects that are within 5 minutes of one another.

So, the result I would get is:

```
[
   {range_start: 2013-06-17 19:40:01, range_end: 2013-06-17 19:47:12},
   {range_start: 2013-06-17 19:12:27, range_end: 2013-06-17 19:14:17},
]
```

As you can see, the first object in the result set would contain all 4 DateTime objects in the example above by getting the earliest time and latest time and making a range. Likewise for the second.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is group together DateTimes that are within 5 minutes of each other, however I'm not sure how to do it without excessive recursion. For example, once I grab the first DateTime and I find another that is within 5 minutes of it, I then need to find all the other DateTime items that are within 5 minutes of the recently found DateTime.

1. Start at minute 42
2. Search 5 minutes before and after
3. Find another DateTime at minute 44, so now range is 42-44
4. Need to search 5 minutes before and after range of 42-44 (so anything from 38 to 49)
5. If I find something at minute 49, then range goes to 42-49
6. Now search radius is 38 to 54, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't going to post this as it was so close to `sawa`'s solution. However this is a working solution whereas his has a couple of major issues.

```
require 'time'

array = [
    '2013-06-17 19:47:12',
    '2013-06-17 19:40:01',
    '2013-06-17 19:42:53',
    '2013-06-17 19:12:27',
    '2013-06-17 19:45:42',
    '2013-06-17 19:14:17'
].map { |dt| DateTime.parse(dt) }

prev_dt = nil

ranges = array.sort.slice_before do |dt|
  is_new_range = prev_dt && (dt - prev_dt) * 1440 > 5
  prev_dt = dt
  is_new_range
end.map { |range| { range_start: range.first, range_end: range.last } }

ranges.each { |r| p r }
```

**output**

```
{:range_start=>#<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:12:27+00:00 ((2456461j,69147s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :range_end=>#<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:14:17+00:00 ((2456461j,69257s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}
{:range_start=>#<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:40:01+00:00 ((2456461j,70801s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, :range_end=>#<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:47:12+00:00 ((2456461j,71232s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}
```

Comment: This worked incredibly well and is quite efficient. `slice_before` is an incredible enumerable that will surely help in the future of the project! Thanks :)

Comment: @BrianW I would be curious to hear what issues my solution have.

Comment: @sawa: I have realised since I wrote that that the problems arose because you intended your code to work on an array of `Time` objects. The OP said that his data is `DateTime`, and the difference is the reason for his data not being split properly as he commented on your post. Another triviality is that the key in the result hashes should be `:range_end`, not `:range_max`. I did give you a +1 though!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the time array does not include the unix epoch:

```
array
.sort
.unshift(Time.at(0))
.each_cons(2)
.slice_before{|t1, t2| t1 + 300 < t2}
.map{|a| min, max = a.map(&:last).minmax; {range_start: min, range_end: max}}
```

Comment: Wow, a lot to look at here! I'm an enumerable newbie so I'll have to look a few of these up. It made the range correctly except it didn't break apart if two dates were more than 5 minutes apart from the range. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd go about it:

```
require 'time'

FIVE_MINUTES = 60 * 5

timestamps = [
  '2013-06-17 19:47:12', 
  '2013-06-17 19:40:01', 
  '2013-06-17 19:42:53', 
  '2013-06-17 19:12:27', 
  '2013-06-17 19:45:42', 
  '2013-06-17 19:14:17'
].map{ |s| Time.parse(s) }.sort

ranges = [timestamps.first .. timestamps.shift]
loop do
  break if timestamps.empty?
  if (timestamps.first - ranges.last.max) <= FIVE_MINUTES
    ranges[-1] = (ranges.last.min .. timestamps.shift)
  else
    ranges << (timestamps.first .. timestamps.shift)
  end
end

pp ranges.map{ |r|
  Hash[
    :range_start, r.min,
    :range_end, r.max
  ]
}
```

Which is an array of hashes:

```
[
  {
    :range_start => 2013-06-17 19:12:27 -0700,
    :range_end   => 2013-06-17 19:14:17 -0700
  },
 {
    :range_start => 2013-06-17 19:40:01 -0700,
    :range_end   => 2013-06-17 19:47:12 -0700
  }
]
```

I converted the DateTime strings to Time values because you get an integer in seconds when subtracting them. That worked well when comparing to `FIVE_MINUTES`. If you need DateTime objects, you can convert them easily using:

```
pp ranges.map{ |r|
  Hash[
    :range_start, r.min.to_datetime,
    :range_end, r.max.to_datetime
  ]
}
```

Which now looks like:

```
[
  {
    :range_start=> #<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:12:27-07:00 ((2456462j,7947s,0n),-25200s,2299161j)>,
    :range_end=> #<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:14:17-07:00 ((2456462j,8057s,0n),-25200s,2299161j)>
  },
  {
    :range_start=> #<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:40:01-07:00 ((2456462j,9601s,0n),-25200s,2299161j)>,
    :range_end=> #<DateTime: 2013-06-17T19:47:12-07:00 ((2456462j,10032s,0n),-25200s,2299161j)>
  }
]
```

I sorted the array because that made it pretty straightforward to find values that were within the five minute boundaries of each other. That results in the ranges being sorted also.

Comment: This produces the same result as Borodin below. I chose his answer as the correct one only because it was slightly faster in a test between the two. But, thank you very much for the answer!